# binary search with vectors in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

im writing a binary search method for a university assignment, and although i feel like this is the correct way of doing it, I feel like the run time is longer then it should be.. does anyone see any mistakes in this? `iterator` is a custom class, nothing fancy, does what you would expect it to. `vec` is a vector of iterators, that point to a bigger linked list of what im "really" searching for

```
iterator searchVec(const I& item)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = (int)vec.size()-1;
    int mid = (right+left)/2;

    while(*vec.at(left) != *vec.at(right)){
        mid = (right+left)/2;
        if (mid == 0 || mid == vec.size()-1){
            //nothign else to search, we didnt find anything
            return *vec.end();
        }
        if (*vec.at(mid) == item){
            return vec.at(mid);
        }
        else if (item > *vec.at(mid)){
            left = mid;
        }
        else if (item < *vec.at(mid)){
            right = mid;
        }
    }
    return vec.at(mid);
}
```

Comment: You cannot dereference `vec.end()`. Nor should you, since you want to return an *iterator*, not a value.

Comment: great point, I modified it to `return vec.at(vec.size()-1);`

Comment: To state the obvious, you're sure your vector is sorted (and that the sort uses the comparison on the derefenced values), right? Also, you will never find an item that is pointed to by the first or last iterator because you test `if (mid == 0 || mid == vec.size()-1)` before `if (*vec.at(mid) == item)`. You don't need that first check, you should remove it.

Comment: Then what if the vector is empty? No, returning an iterator is generally a good idea, you just have to get all the details right.

Comment: vector.at() does not return an iterator. Why are you dereferencing it? Is this a vector of pointers to type I?

Comment: "Is this a vector of pointers to type I?" yes, well rather a vector of iterators that point to type I

Comment: Now I noticed the questions tells it, sorry. It seems fine to me. You could output information to console before the while ends and see if it dives into wrong parts of the vector.

Comment: You can also remove one of your boolean checks. A proper strong-order should be able to do this with two `operator<()` only. `if (a < b) ... else if (b < a) .... else they're equal` thereby only requiring the single is-less-than operator for the underlying type, and no greater-than or equality operators at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- You are using `std::vector::at` which is [slow compared to `std::vector::operator[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269809/stdvectorat-vs-operator-surprising-results-5-to-10-times-slower-f).
- You cannot dereference `vec.end()`. Usually, it is returned if you want to signal the caller that no item was found. But here, as you do not return an iterator of `vec`, maybe you should signal this with a boolean out parameter or an exception.
- The loop condition doesn't look right to me. It seems it should be `left <= right` instead of `*vec[left] != *vec[right]`. Then the aim of the loop is to select the item. If we break out of the loop, then no item is found.
- The exit condition is useless and will prevent finding first and last element, as stated in the comments.

  ```
      if (mid == 0 || mid == vec.size()-1)
          //nothign else to search, we didnt find anything
          return *vec.end();
      }
  ```

Here is a slightly corrected code:

```
iterator searchVec(const I& item)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = (int)vec.size()-1;
    int mid = (right+left)/2;

    while(left <= right) // corrected condition
    {
        mid = (right+left)/2;
        iterator it = vec[mid]; // avoid recomputing vec[mid]
        if (*it == item) // this can be moved in a else {} statement,
            return it;   // after the else if (no impact on performances I think)
        else if (item > *it)
            left = mid + 1; // you were not strictly decreasing the interval
        else if (item < *it)
            right = mid - 1; // same here
    }
    throw not_found();
}
```