# Why is undefined behavior allowed in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, undefined-behavior

By default, the "underlying container" of an `std::stack` is an `std::deque`. Therefore anything that is undefined behavior for a `std::deque` is undefined behavior for a `std::stack`. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) and other sites use the terminology "effectively" when describing the behavior of member functions. I take this to mean that it is for all intents and purposes. So therefore, calling `top()` and `pop()` is equivalent to calling `back()` and `pop_back()`, and calling these on an empty container is undefined behavior.

From my understanding, the reason why it's undefined behavior is to preserve the no-throw guarantee. My reasoning is that `operator[]` for `std::vector` has a no-throw guarantee and is undefined behavior if container size is greater than N, but `at()` has a strong guarantee, and throws `std::out_of_range` if n is out of bounds.

So my question is, what is the rationale behind some things having possibly undefined behavior and having a no throw guarantee versus having a strong guarantee but throwing an exception instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When undefined behaviour is allowed, it's *usually* for reasons of efficiency.

If the standard specified what has to happen when you access an array out of bounds, it would force the implementation to check whether the index is in bounds. Same goes for a vector, which is just a wrapper for a dynamic array.

In other cases the behaviour is allowed to be undefined in order to allow freedom in the implementation. But that, too, is really about efficiency (as some possible implementation strategies could be more efficient on some machines than on others, and C++ leaves it up to the implementer to pick the most efficient strategy, if they so desire.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm) one marked reason is efficiency. He states that the standard does not impose any requirements on `operator[]`'s exception specification or whether or not it requires bound checking. This is up to the implementation.

> On the other hand, `vector<T>::operator[]()` is allowed, but not
>   required, to perform bounds checking. There's not a breath of wording
>   in the standard's specification for `operator[]()` that says anything
>   about bounds checking, but neither is there any requirement that it
>   have an exception specification, so your standard library implementer
>   is free to add bounds-checking to `operator[]()`, too. So, if you use
>   `operator[]()` to ask for an element that's not in the vector, you're
>   on your own, and the standard makes no guarantees about what will
>   happen (although your standard library implementation's documentation
>   might) -- your program may crash immediately, the call to
>   `operator[]()` might throw an exception, or things may seem to work
>   and occasionally and/or mysteriously fail.
>
> Given that bounds checking protects us against many common problems,
>   why isn't `operator[]()` required to perform bounds checking? The
>   short answer is: Efficiency. Always checking bounds would cause a
>   (possibly slight) performance overhead on all programs, even ones that
>   never violate bounds. The spirit of C++ includes the dictum that, by
>   and large, you shouldn't have to pay for what you don't use, and so
>   bounds checking isn't required for `operator[]()`. In this case we
>   have an additional reason to want the efficiency: vectors are intended
>   to be used instead of built-in arrays, and so should be as efficient
>   as built-in arrays, which don't do bounds-checking. If you want to be
>   sure that bounds get checked, use `at()` instead.

If you're curious about the performance benefits, see these two questions:

1. [::std::vector::at() vs operator[] << surprising results!! 5 to 10 times slower/faster!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269809/stdvectorat-vs-operator-surprising-results-5-to-10-times-slower-f)
2. [vector::at vs. vector::operator[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376049/vectorat-vs-vectoroperator)

The consensus seems to be that `operator[]` is more efficient (since `std::vector` is just a wrapper around a dynamic array, `operator[]` should be just as efficient as if you would call it on an array.) And Herb Sutter seems to suggest that whether or not it is exception-safe is up to the compiler-vendor.